# Domian controller Sync

Tags: domain

We have DC controller in Del and we have 1 ADC and 2 chile domain controller with DNS in mum. Now one of our child DC + DHCP server went down so we shifted it to another DC. But now this DC is dwon for more than 2 months. We areplace the hardware and start the server. Do we need to take care of something so that it dosen't create any problem in the current enviroment.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. To improve the quality of your question and get a better answer, please try to avoid using abbreviations which will not be understood by a worldwide audience. For instance, I can't determine for certain what you mean by "Del" and "mum" (I guess you mean Delhi and Mumbai, but I am not sure). You may make corrections to your question by clicking the `edit` link which appears directly below it.

Answer (score 1):

Before bringing it back online, check the tombstone value in AD as when the domain controllers are re-introduced deleted objects may start re-appearing and other unpredictable behaviour may occur.  Windows 2000 AD had a tombstone value of 60, which changed to 180 days in Windows 2003 SP2.

From a commandline run
`dsquery * "cn=Directory Service,cn=Windows NT,cn=Services,cn=Configuration,dc=contoso,dc=local" -scope base -attr tombstonelifetime`

Replace `"dc=contoso,dc=local"` with your AD domain name.

If your tombstone is 60 days, I'd remove that server from AD, do a metadata cleanup, wipe it and reload.